# composer.phar update then Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Tags: php, apache, syntax-error, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend Framework 2.

After an update (I guess quite long because I had to use "COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=5000 php composer.phar update"). I get this strange error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end"... so I add to the end of the current file an "?>" but another file error has coming with this similar error.. If you see every files of Zend Framework 2 (or ex: 1.11), no one has this end.

So my question is : It's a mistake of the composer.phar when updating or a mistake with my PHP  (php.ini) ?

To explain with a concrete example, I'm trying to install "socalnick/scn-social-auth". So I changed the composer.json file according the installation (https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth) then these errors.

Somebody has this kind of error ?

Thanks a lot
Have a good day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.. shame on me ! Just after an update of Debian

```
# apt-get update 
# apt-get upgrade
```

The website is back !

## Last update

It seems the problem is coming from **the virtual machine** (I'm using VMware) so just **reboot** your virtual machine and all will be perfect !
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1365

Comment: Is your website still available after composer has updated any dependencies (i.e. after "composer update")? I have to restart my VM every time...

Comment: Not every times it's available, I have to check your solution to restart the server (or VM). The "bug" is performed when updating big libraries (like ZF,Scn-social-auth...)

Answer (score 4):

At first, updating Debian as Remi Thomas suggested worked.
But when using Composer to install the project again, the same problem occured.

In my case it looks like the culprit is my setup, which is a virtual machine (VMWare Fusion) and shared folders between guest and host. Luckily, all I have to do is to restart the virtual machine and what do you know, the problem goes away.

For anyone else having the same problem, maybe this can save you a couple of hours worth of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change in composer.json

"zendframework/zendframework": "dev-master",

to

"zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",

I've seen some strange behaviour with "dev-master" settings.

Comment: I changed the version of ZF but nothing happens. I get still the same errors.
I have checked too the php.ini with **short_open_tag** but nothing..